# centerColor in GradientDrawable XML results in error

Tags: android, xml, drawable, gradient

I'm trying to use XML drawables to create drop shadow for some tabs.

I'm using a gradient and if I use only two colors, it looks like this:

[image]

If I add a third color using "centerColor", then it looks like this:

[image]

I also get this error in eclipse:

```
Failed to convert 00DDDDDD into a ColorStateList
```

This is the code with only two colors (No error):

```
<!-- Shadow on left -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="#DDDDDD"
            android:endColor="#00DDDDDD"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

This is the XML with three colors:

```
<!-- Shadow on left -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="#DDDDDD"
            android:centerColor="#00DDDDDD"
            android:endColor="#00DDDDDD" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I've double and triple checked all the syntax and I'm positive that I've done it right so I'm completely stumped as to why I'm getting an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Stack trace added:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value '00DDDDDD' must start with #
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColor(ResourceHelper.java:71)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColorStateList(ResourceHelper.java:147)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getColor(BridgeTypedArray.java:325)
at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:875)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:168)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:208)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:782)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:623)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor70.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:86)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:131)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:399)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:336)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:504)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1066)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegateActivated(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:743)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.activated(CommonXmlEditor.java:416)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.LayoutWindowCoordinator.partActivated(LayoutWindowCoordinator.java:379)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService$6.run(PartService.java:131)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.partActivated(PartService.java:129)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$15.run(WorkbenchPage.java:4794)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.firePartActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:4792)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$16(WorkbenchPage.java:4772)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:194)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$2.run(PartServiceImpl.java:192)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:190)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:609)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:553)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:104)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer$10.widgetSelected(StackRenderer.java:940)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:778)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3080)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1772)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:279)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Comment: maybe you need to specify type and angle attributes. what happens if You try android:angle="90", android:type="linear" ?

Comment: Sorry, that's a no go. Didn't change anything.

Comment: Further, changing the colors didn't help either. Using all unique colors, or changing them all to RGB or ARGB values didn't change the error.

Comment: I pulled an exception stack trace and added it above.

Comment: Have You tried to clean Your project? If not, do it, delete the apk from Your device and reinstall it.

Comment: I didn't clean my project but restarting Eclipse seems to have fixed the issue. Must have been some weird eclipse bug. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Restarting eclipse is also cleaning the project. The thing is, maybe You have put the value of Your color without using #, and build it, then You saw this and corrected it. But in the R.java file, sometimes it doesn´t change such things.